# socket.io client and server socket.id different

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am having trouble with socket server and client socket.id. With `node@5.6.0` and `socket@1.4.6` I am getting different `socket.id` from client (`socket.io-client`) and server (`socket`) not sure if this is expected in the latest version? e.i the difference is that the server side `socket.id` has `/#IAPEFvUDQkfV0NxcAAAA` and client side `socket.id` has `IAPEFvUDQkfV0NxcAAAA` where as if I use the `socket@1.3.1` I get the same socket.id from client and server.

This is the version...

```
admin$ npm list | grep socket
├─┬ socket.io@1.4.6
│ ├─┬ socket.io-adapter@0.4.0
│ │ └─┬ socket.io-parser@2.2.2
│ ├─┬ socket.io-client@1.4.6
│ └─┬ socket.io-parser@2.2.6
├─┬ socket.io-client@1.3.1
│ ├─┬ socket.io-parser@2.2.2
├─┬ socket.io-stream@0.6.1
admin$ npm --version
3.6.0
admin$ node --version
v5.6.0
admin$
```

This is the server `test_socket_server` code

```
# test_socket_server.js
var io = require('socket.io').listen(5000);
var serverurl = "http://0.0.0.0:5000/";

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var socketid = socket.id
    console.log('serversocketid', socketid)
    socket.on('get_socketid_from_client', function(clientsocketid) {
        console.log('get_socketid_from_client-clientsocketid', clientsocketid)
        io.to(clientsocketid).emit('test_emit_on_clientsocketid')
        io.to('/#'+clientsocketid).emit('test_emit_on_clientsocketid_modified')
        socket.emit('test_emit_on_serversocketid')
    })
});
```

This is the client `test_socket_client` code

```
# test_socket_client.js
var io_client = require('socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client')
var serverurl = "http://0.0.0.0:5000/";
var options = {
        transports: ['websocket'],
        'force new connection': true
};
var socket = io_client.connect(serverurl, options);
socket.on("connect", function () {
    console.log('clientsocketid', socket.id);
    socket.emit('get_socketid_from_client', socket.id, function(data) {
        console.log('get_socketid_from_client', data)
    });
});
socket.on("test_emit_on_clientsocketid", function () {
    console.log('test_emit_on_clientsocketid successful')
});
socket.on("test_emit_on_clientsocketid_modified", function () {
    console.log('test_emit_on_clientsocketid_modified successful')
});
socket.on("test_emit_on_serversocketid", function () {
    console.log('test_emit_on_serversocketid successful')
});
```

These are the result...

```
# Server side
$ node test_socket_server.js
serversocketid /#IAPEFvUDQkfV0NxcAAAA
get_socketid_from_client-clientsocketid IAPEFvUDQkfV0NxcAAAA

$

# Client side
$ node test_socket_client.js
clientsocketid IAPEFvUDQkfV0NxcAAAA
test_emit_on_clientsocketid_modified successful
test_emit_on_serversocketid successful

$
```

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late but seems that this was fixed in the last version released a few days ago.

The first item in [release notes of version 1.5.0](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/releases) says that they stopped append /# before id when no namespace